# prevent <img> tag from inheriting css style from unknown source

Tags: css, magento, image, inheritance

Is there a way to absolutely force inline html or php to not inherit ? Otherwise I may need assistance tracking how code is being added inline

I am trying to add shareasale tracking code to a Magento success page, using the following code:

```
<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?tracking=<?php echo $this->getOrderId() ?>&amount=<?php echo $_sub ?>&transtype=sale&merchantID=XXXX" width="1" height="1">
```

However, when rending the page, my template is transforming it into:

```
<img width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;" src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?tracking=<<correct number>>&amp;amount=<<correct number>>&amp;transtype=sale&amp;merchantID=<<correct number>>">
```

ie:

- changing the inline width and height from 1 to 0
- inserting display:none, visibility: hidden  - which prevent the code from working

Based on chrome's element inspector, these are element.styles and not part of the sheet, but I have no idea how they are getting added to the that image tag

---

I have tried to force the img code above within a php echo and outside, and also try to add style="display: inline !important;" but no difference.  I also grep searched 'display: none ! important' in all css, js (javascript) and template folders to try and identify the source and could not

---

Thanks in advance for any tips and help

Comment: Well you won't be able to override an inline css tag with !important with a parent css sheet. so you better figure out where the styles are added in the first place

Comment: Have you tried disabling JS to see if that's the culprit?  You can try this trick, but it would be better to find out the source of the problem if you can:  http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Also possibly, do you have some sort of AdBlock-like extension? Most tracking systems like that are -blam-ed with in various ways by such extensions, with the deliberate intention of breaking them.

Comment: joequincy nailed it - it was chrome's adblock, once that was disabled the shareasale img showed correctly...joequincy, you may want to answer officially so i can mark that as the accepted answer...thanks to everyone who contributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit to joequincy: Also possibly, do you have some sort of AdBlock-like extension? Most tracking systems like that are -blam-ed with in various ways by such extensions, with the deliberate intention of breaking them. – joequincy

ie turning off adblock worked

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple peices of Javascript all interacting with the same tag, it can become difficult to track down the script that's responsible for specific changes.  Fortunately, both Chrome and Firebug have tools that allow you to pause script execution on any line of Javascript code that modified an attribute (e.g. style) on a given tag or subtree.  The best suggestion I can offer would be to load the page in Chrome, and open up the inspector.  Right click on the img tag you're interested in and select Break on Modification, then refresh the page and see where the breakpoints occur.